# Async loading of UITableView cells with RxSwift

Tags: android, ios, rx-java, rx-swift, reactivex

I'm trying to leverage RxSwift in my app. One of the use cases is an async loading of an image UITableView which is triggered by a search button (or recycling of the cell). What I can't get to work well is discarding previous results.

It's important for me to keep a correct loading order, as well as being able to discard network requests for unneeded images

> I'm working on RxSwift, but this could apply to RxJava and Android RecyclerView

A pseudo code of the current state is:

```
myModel
  .searchString
  .debounce(0.3)
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .flatMapLatest({ return fetchImageUrlsFromNetwork($0) })
  .bindTo(tableView.rx.items) { (url,cell,...) in
     reactivelyLoadUrl(url)
        .subscribe({ cell.imageView.image = UIImage(data:$0) })
  }
```

The problem in the code, of course, is the lack of connection between the cell observable and the outer observable, which I know is a bad practice,

but I'm not sure how to use the RxCocoa bindings for UITableView with combination of the cell async loading. The fact that the internals of the tableview use load when scrolling and recycling of cells also adds some complexities to this scenario.

It's also important that I wouldn't have to load all tableview data beforehand and therefore display all cells images at the same time.

I was thinking about maybe creating a global observable per tableview index so when it is required by the UI engine (either triggered by recycling or by search engine result callback) the request would go into a sequence which is applied with the `flatMapLatest` operator and thus the loading would preserve order per cell, but it's not so elegant.

The result is that if I run quickly several search queries, I can see previous image loadings overriding new ones sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of challenging problems that RxSwift can help you work through.  Personally I've found this particular one to not be one.  I feel like loading results from a model to the table view, is trivial and clean when using Rx.  To return associated data for that tableView though after is not.

I'd consider using a library such as KingFisher / SDWebImage to tackle this secondary problem.